# Find the winner and maximum nodes visited by winner for Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search, game-theory

Given a *Graph* with N nodes. Two players A and B start from node 1 and node N respectively. A can visit all the adjacent nodes to the nodes already visited by A but can not visit any nodes which are already visited by B and similarly for B also. Suppose A moves first. Find the winner and maximum nodes visited by the winner.
I know a solution for the tree using DFS, but for Graph, I am not able to construct a solution.

Comment: Does A have a current position from which he must move to an adjacent node or can he take any node on his next move that is adjacent to one taken before?

Comment: A has a current position from which he must move to an adjacent node

Comment: Ask yourself, which paths of length n visit n different nodes?

Comment: Perform DFS for A and DFS for B. One step for A, then one step for B and repeat. Stop when both have no more nodes to visit, The winner is the one with the longest visited list.